# tSQLt - How does AssertEqualsTable work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt

tSQLt has a command called AssertEqualsTable that tests whether contents of 2 tables match.

I would like to understand how the logic works, does it use the first column as a JOIN between the 2 tables, to then test whether the rest of the columns for that row (join) match?

Comment: https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/blob/master/Source/tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable.ssp.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssertEqualsTable compares the whole row - i.e. all columns.  For example if the `expected` table has one row of four columns ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') and `actual` also has one row ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E'), the result returned by `AssertEqualsTable` will show two rows - the ABCD row expected not found plus the ABCE row returned but NOT expected.

There is is no guarantee that the expected and actual tables in every single test that anyone might want to write would even have a unique key so the comparison has to be based on the whole row.